# How to add close text to datetimepicker bootstrap?

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

```
$(function() {
    $('input.month-mode').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'months',
        format: 'MM/YYYY',
        showClose: true,
        maxDate: current_month,
    });
});
```

I want to add close text to it. by default it shows 'X', but I want to change it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [icons](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#icons) option to define a custom css class for your icon and then you can write a css rule to customize close text as shown below:

```js
$(function () {
    var current_month = moment(); // just a sample value
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        showClose: true,
        viewMode: 'months',
        format: 'MM/YYYY',
        maxDate: current_month,
        icons: {
            close: 'closeText'
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.closeText:before {
    content: "Close";
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the icon classes to a add a new class and then use css to add some content. Something like:

```
$(function() {
        $('input.month-mode').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'months',
            format: 'MM/YYYY',
            showClose: true,
            maxDate: current_month,
            icons: {
                close: 'textclass1'
                }
        });
    });
```

Css:

```
.textclass1::before {
  content: "Close";
}
```